# Algorithm for Dead end detection in the path

Tags: python, python-2.7, graph-theory

I am trying to write a code to detect if a node of a non directed graph is in a dead end or not using python. Do you have any ideas how this could be computed efficiently.

Here is an example code:

```
class SimpleGraph:
    def __init__(self):
        self.edges = {}

    def neighbors(self, id):
        return self.edges[id]

    def empty(self):
        self.edges = {}

example_graph = SimpleGraph()
example_graph.edges = {
    'A': ['B', 'D'],
    'B': ['A', 'C'],
    'C': ['B', 'D', 'E'],
    'D': ['A', 'C'],
    'E': ['C', 'F'],
    'F': ['E']
}
```

Only the nodes E and F are in a dead end. For this reason, I would like to be able to return a dictionary such as follow:
{A: False, B: False, C: False, D: False, E: True, F: True}

Comment: Are you sure your graph is non-directed? If so, why does A's neighbor list contain C, but C's neighbor list doesn't contain A? Furthermore, why is E a dead end if it has two neighbors?

Comment: Please give a definition for what you mean by "is in a dead end".

Comment: Going to go ahead and remove my answer as I dont think it is correct based on the question. Please answer the questions above so we can revisit.

Comment: @Kevin, there was a typo, just corrected it. Good point.

Comment: @ZackTarr: A node is not in a dead end when you can leave from this node using an edge E1 and enter to the same node using an edge different from E1.

Comment: So a dead end is a node with degree 1?

Comment: Can a dead-end node have more than one non-dead-end neighbor? Consider the graph at https://i.stack.imgur.com/b78RU.png. You can't leave D via C and enter it via E, and vice versa, so does that make it a dead end?

Comment: It sounds like a "dead end" is any node which is not in a cycle. So you can reduce your question to detecting if each node is in a cycle.

Answer (score 0):

Undeleted my answer for now to see if it helps.

I am a bit confused on what you are asking based on your desired output. In your output you are saying both E and F are dead ends.  But how is the rest not also a dead end in your logic since C->E->F becomes a dead end, and then since ABD all point towards C wouldnt they also be a dead end?

Your Output: `{A: False, B: False, C: False, D: False, E: True, F: True}`

I wrote the code below to determine if an element is a dead end, meaning it does not point to any location except for the element that points to it. So the only one to be true in that logic is F. Since it only points to E which is what points to F.

```
edges = {
    'A': ['B', 'C'],
    'B': ['A', 'C'],
    'C': ['B', 'D', 'E'],
    'D': ['A', 'C'],
    'E': ['C', 'F'],
    'F': ['E']
}
out={}
def dead_end(elem):
    if(len(edges[elem])>1):
        out[elem]=False
        return
    else:
        out[elem]=True

for i in edges:
    dead_end(i)
print(out)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this:

```
def dead_ends(self):
    dead_ends = {}
    ends = []
    # Find all ends of graphs
    for node in self.edges:
        if len(self.edges[node]) == 1 :
            dead_ends[node] = True
            ends.append(node)
        else :
            dead_ends[node] = False

    print(dead_ends)
    # Copy edges:
    local_edges = {}
    for node in self.edges:
        local_edges[node] = self.edges[node]

    # Starts from ends to crawl back the graph
    for node in ends:
        # For each end of graph found
        continue_to_crawl = True  # Sets a boolean to stop the while loop
        current_node = node # Sets current node to node
        while continue_to_crawl :
            if dead_ends[current_node] == True and len(local_edges[current_node]) == 1: 
                next_node = local_edges[current_node][0] # finds next node
                dead_ends[next_node] = True # Sets dead_ends for the next node as a dead end
                del local_edges[current_node] # removes key for current node
                local_edges[next_node].remove(current_node) # Removes current node from the next node edge list
                current_node = next_node

            elif len(local_edges[current_node]) > 1:
                break
```

I am unsure about why you want 'C' to be `False` and not `True`, since it's the first node to a dead end, I ran out of ideas as how to set the nodes in this case to False but this is a basis you can work on.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to find all nodes that aren't part of any cycle. A node is part of a cycle if and only if it is part of some [biconnected component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biconnected_component) of the graph with size >= 3. Thus, you can find "dead end" nodes by running a standard biconnected components algorithm over your graph and picking the nodes that are not part of a biconnected component of size >= 3.